# How to mask and modify DIV's width in tilt?

Tags: jquery, css

I have 4 pictures on different DIV's. The trick I want to achieve is to have them masked inside the tilted rectangles. When the user hovers one of the rectangles then it spreads a bit to show more of the picture.

[Static example.](http://img221.imageshack.us/img221/9793/testgq.jpg)

I would like to achieve this using HTML, jQuery and CSS, without any SWFs. The solutions is quite easy when you think about the regular rectangles but when the tilt shape comes into play then the magic beggins.

Any ideas welcome!

Comment: What have you come up with so far and what doesn't work?

Comment: I have come up with a standard cropping. But don't have any idea how to apply tilt shapes.

Comment: You could use canvas for your tilt shapes: http://jsfiddle.net/peteng/KAkvX/

Comment: @friedman I have been playing with the canvas stuff as I wanted to learn it and came up with this if it will help you: http://jsfiddle.net/peteng/AGPrU/

Comment: This is great! Exactly the way that I wanted to see it. The question is to which browsers (back) is this compatible?

Comment: OK, I can see http://caniuse.com/#search=canvas :) Thank you again!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with html5 canvas and paper.js.

```
createSplitPictures(["http://img.over-blog.com/600x450/4/26/15/99/Novembre-2012/image-jaune1.jpg",  "http://www.gratuit-en-ligne.com/telecharger-gratuit-en-ligne/telecharger-image-wallpaper-gratuit/image-wallpaper-animaux/img/images/image-wallpaper-animaux-chatons.jpg" , "http://www.desktopwallpaperhd.net/thumbs/19/5/islands-paradise-maldive-nature-background-image-landscape-194469.jpg" , "http://img.over-blog.com/600x450/4/26/15/99/Novembre-2012/image-jaune1.jpg"]);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/HDmCN/1/

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to use HTML 5 canvas and change paths of your images.
I have created jsfiddle that may help you.

http://jsfiddle.net/ihordeyneka/NKbBD/

```
var canvas = document.getElementById('myCanvas');
var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
var pattern = null;
var currentSize = 100;
var step = 1;
var direction = 1;

var imageObj = new Image();
imageObj.onload = function() {
pattern = context.createPattern(imageObj, 'repeat');
setInterval(draw, 10);
};
imageObj.src = 'http://www.html5canvastutorials.com/demos/assets/wood-pattern.png';

function draw() {
context.clearRect(0, 0, 200, 200);
context.beginPath();
context.moveTo(25,25);
context.lineTo(currentSize,25);
context.lineTo(25,currentSize);

context.closePath();
context.fillStyle = pattern;
context.fill();

currentSize += direction * step;
if(currentSize > 150){
    direction = -1;
}
if(currentSize < 50){
    direction = 1;
}
};
```